# mysql get attendance of all students for each date in a range

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following tables
Students Table

```
id  name
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
```

And Atendance table

```
student_id   status  date
1              P      2020-02-14
2              P      2020-02-14
1              A      202-02-15
```

What I want is that the attendance should be shown for all dates, irrespective of data is present in the data tables or not. I have tried the following query

```
SELECT student.name, attendance.status 
from student
  LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.id = attendance.student_id
                      AND attendance.date = '2020-02-14'
```

With the above query I get the output as

```
id  name   status     date
1    A1      P      2020-02-14
2    A2      P      2020-02-14
3    A3      null   null
```

But I want the output to be

```
id  name   status     date
1    A1      P      2020-02-14
2    A2      P      2020-02-14
3    A3      null   2020-02-14
1    A1      A      2020-02-15
2    A2      null   2020-02-15
3    A3      null   2020-02-15
```

Is is possible to achieve the above output using a single query? Or do I need to do some operations by converting the query output into JSON to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is no date on which all students have no record of their attendance, you can find all the relevant dates from the attendance table with a `SELECT DISTINCT` query; then you can `CROSS JOIN` this to the `students` table and `LEFT JOIN` to attendance to get your desired result:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, a.status, d.date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM attendance) d
CROSS JOIN students s
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.date = d.date AND a.student_id = s.id
ORDER BY d.date, s.id
```

Output:

```
id  name    status  date
1   A1      P       2020-02-14
2   A2      P       2020-02-14
3   A3      null    2020-02-14
1   A1      A       2020-02-15
2   A2      null    2020-02-15
3   A3      null    2020-02-15
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hAf5CCW69wNMYJrS1mM263/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates.  Then a cross join and left join:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2020-02-14') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < '2020-02-16'
    )
select s.id, s.name, a.status, d.dte
from dates d cross join
     students s left join
     attendance a
     on a.student_id = s.id and
        a.date = d.dte;
```